# Turn dictionary into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Python. I have this kind of dictionary, from a geodesic output and i wonder if i can turn this into DataFrame or matrix?
here's an example data, but what i'm working right now has more than 8000 data

```
{(0, 0): 0.0,
 (0, 1): 1.3128088339744233,
 (1, 0): 1.3128088339744233,
 (1, 1): 0.0}
```

desired output would be a DataFrame that looks like this

[image]

or is there any other way to create distance matrix using geodesic from geopy.calculation?

Comment: can you add another example? Bigger than this

Comment: you can simply use the `dict.keys()` as index and `dict.values()` as data for a dataframe, then unstack it over the second index. Check my solution for details.

Comment: One-liner `pd.DataFrame(d.values(), index=d.keys()).unstack(-1).droplevel(0, axis=1)`

Answer (score 3):

Try this -

> I have added additional entries to show how this approach scales to more rows and column indexes, and handles missing row, column indexes as well.

```
d = {(0, 0): 0.0,
     (0, 1): 1.3128088339744233,
     (1, 0): 1.3128088339744233,
     (1, 1): 0.0}

df = pd.DataFrame(d.values(), index=d.keys()).unstack(-1).droplevel(0, axis=1)
print(df)
```

```
          0         1
0  0.000000  1.312809
1  1.312809  0.000000
```

---

Additional test with missing rows and column indexes -

```
d = {(0, 0): 0.0,
     (0, 1): 1.3128088339744233,
     (1, 0): 1.3128088339744233,
     (1, 1): 0.0,
     (1, 2): 1.7,        #More entries
     (2, 1): 2.3}        #More entries

df = pd.DataFrame(d.values(), index=d.keys()).unstack(-1).droplevel(0, axis=1)
print(df)
```

```
          0         1    2
0  0.000000  1.312809  NaN
1  1.312809  0.000000  1.7
2       NaN  2.300000  NaN
```

---

#### Alternate way -

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.index)
df = df.unstack(-1).droplevel(0, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, install pandas

```
import pandas as pd
```

Make use of `pd.DataFrame.from_dict()` function. It has two arguments you need. Columns which specify your column name and orient for row. So go through dictionary key and assign first element as column(row) names and second as row(column).

Source is [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html)

Comment: I think you mean `pd.DataFrame.from_dict()`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```py
dicti = {(0, 0): 0.0,
 (0, 1): 1.3128088339744233,
 (1, 0): 1.3128088339744233,
 (1, 1): 0.0}

rows = [a[0] for a in list(dicti.keys())]
columns = [a[1] for a in list(dicti.keys())]

#only storing unique values for rows and columns
rows = list(dict.fromkeys(rows))
columns = list(dict.fromkeys(columns))

#Initializing empty dict in order to create dataframe from it
df_dict = {}
for val in columns:
  df_dict[val] = []

for k,v in dicti.items():
  df_dict[k[1]].append(v)

df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict, columns=columns, index=rows) #creating DataFrame

df
```